# 'R' replace nested for() loops with aggregate() when labeling with cut()

Tags: r, aggregate

I am interested in putting data into quartiles, where the data is tagged with several different attributes, and I want the quartiles to only apply to the data with those attributes.  This is easy to do (with two attributes) with nested for() loops:

```
df <- data.frame('type1'=rep(50,c('A','B')),'type2'=rep(25,c('D','E','F','G'),'f1'=rnorm(100,mean=0.0,sd=1.0),'f2'=rnorm(100,mean=0.0,sd=1.0)

summary(df)

id_breaks=c(-2.0,-1.0,0,1.0,2.0)

q_df <- NULL

for (t1 in unique(df$type1)) {

    for (t2 in unique(df$type2)) {
        df_sub <- df[df$type1==t1 && df$type2==t2,]
    this_q_df <- within(df_sub,f1_quart <- cut(f1, id_breaks, include.lowest=FALSE,labels=FALSE))

    print(paste("t1",t1,"t2",t2))
    print(head(this_q_df))

    rbind(q_df, this_q_df)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this with `aggregate(df$f1~t1+t2,...`?

Comment: BillPearson, please consider going back to your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10332171/bill-pearson?tab=questions) and accepting answers by clicking on the check-mark; this indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample code have several errors in it, but I think this is what you are looking for.

This can be accomplished with group_by function in the dplyr package:

```
df <- data.frame('type1'=rep(c('A','B'), 50),
                 'type2'=rep(c('D','E','F','G'), 25),
                'f1'=rnorm(100,mean=0.0,sd=1.0),'f2'=rnorm(100,mean=0.0,sd=1.0))
summary(df)

library(dplyr)                                                 
id_breaks=c(-2.0,-1.0,0,1.0,2.0)

df %>% group_by(type1, type2) %>% 
       mutate(f1_quart  = cut(f1, id_breaks, include.lowest=FALSE, labels=FALSE))
```

or maybe this:

```
df %>% group_by(type1, type2) %>% 
      mutate(f1_quart = cut(f1, quantile(df$f1, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.25)), labels=FALSE))
```